# socket.io and node.js: different latency between sending messages from server and from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem with `socket.io.` I would like to perform a bandwidth measurement via WebSocket connection.

the measurement:
I send a message `(with socket.io)` with a defined amount of data from client to server and save a timestamp on clinet-side. if the entire message to the server has been transferred, the server sends back a short notification message. I stop the time and subtract the previously determined latency between client and server. Now I divied the amount of data by the transfer time. This results in the bandwidth for the upload.

I run the same from the server-side to the client to determine the download bandwidth.

But the determined values does not fit. The message from the server to the client is always faster than the message from client to server. even with `synchronous Ethernet connection`.

Why is the upload slower than the download? How can I fix that?
Or is there an easier / better way to measure the bandwidth with `node.js`?

rg Frew

Comment: It's pretty obvious that your "upload" test includes downloading (response) from server.. It's not just the size of the package, but the time needed for process and send response that's important.

Comment: I don't remember the details, but any test like this needs to set certain socket parameters so that the socket won't "pause a short time" waiting for more data before sending your packet (thus messing up your timing calculations).

Comment: If you just want to measure throughput speed, then you can just send a large amount of data (e.g. tens of megabytes) and the latency will be an immaterial part of the overall time (so much smaller than the large data that it becomes insignificant).